# Best practice for setting onclickListener for buttons on an array buttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a class `Game` and an array of buttons `buts`, i want to call function on the Game class `fun(i,j)` when any buts[i][j] is clicked , i tried like this:

```
buts = new JButton[Setting.length][Setting.width];
    Game game = new Game(setting);
    int hgap = 4, vgap = 4;
    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(Setting.length, Setting.width, hgap, vgap));
for (int i = 0; i < Setting.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Setting.width; j++) {
                //JButton btn = new JButton();
                buts[i][j] = new JButton();
                buts[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(j));
                setColor(buts[i][j], Game.cells[i][j].getColor());
                buts[i][j].addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        buttonActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(buts[i][j]);
            }
        }
    private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
```

but how can i send i,j to the function `buttonActionPerformed` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a concrete [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for each `JButton` and pass in the values `i` & `j` into the constructor of the class.

**Adding:**

```
buts[i][j].setAction(new MyAction(i, j));
```

**The `Action` implementation:**

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
   private final int iValue;
   private final int jValue;

   public MyAction(int i, int j) {
      this.iValue = i;
      this.jValue = j;
   }

   @Override    
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      buttonActionPerformed(e, iValue, jValue);
   }
}
```

**And:**

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt, int i, int j) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyActionListener implemments ActionListener{

     private final int i;
     private final int j;
     MyActionListener (int i, int j){
          this.i = i;
          this.j = j;
     }
}

buts[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener(i,j) {
       public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    buttonActionPerformed(evt,this.i,this.j);
       }
});

private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt,int i,int j) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- you can compare the source of the event (`ActionEvent#getSource()`) with the buttons in the array, and retrieve `i` and `j`. Drawback is that you keep on looping over the array
- you can pass `i` and `j` to either an `Action` or the `ActionListener` as suggested in the other answers
- you can use the `JComponent#putClientProperty` and `JComponent#getClientProperty` methods to store `i` and `j` in the `JButton`. Accessing the `JButton` can be done with the `ActionEvent#getSource` method

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way of doing this would have to pull setting the actionListener into a function, and declare i and j final.  So you'd set up your buttons like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Setting.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Setting.width; j++) {
            //JButton btn = new JButton();
            buts[i][j] = new JButton();
            buts[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(j));
            setColor(buts[i][j], Game.cells[i][j].getColor());
            setButtonAction(buts[i][j], i, j);
            panel.add(buts[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

And declare the method `setButtonAction` like this:

```
public void setButtonAction(JButton button, final int i, final int j){
    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            fun(i,j);
        }
    });
}
```

You could also do all this without an extra method, but then you'd have to declare some final int variables and transfer the value of i and j over to the finals... it just would look ugly.